# Checking Status and capturing date and updating item

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, updatelistitems

I have a flow I'm attempting to build where it has a status column with several statuses. 
In progress
Submitted
On Hold
Completed

Once the status of Completed is selected. I'm using a flow to check and see if there was a change to the status column. If there is a change I'm using an additional condition to see if the date field is empty and if the status field value is equal to complete.

If the status field is complete but there is no date in the date field I use utcNow() to get the current date and update the date field. That said something in my logic isn't working properly.

The current trigger and steps are:
When an Item is modified
 Get changes for an item or file
 Check condition, has status column changed is equal to true
 Continues to yes branch
 Condition 2 in yes branch, Status value is equal to Completed and Completion date field is equal to empty or null.

From there I'm trying to get the yes branch to update the the items date field with the date completed was selected.

I have the update item action but I believe there is something wrong with my Condition 2 yes branch. it gets through the first just fine but the second condition is where I think it falls apart. Additionally I'm not sure if I should us utcNow() or today() when updating the date field.